# How to avoid memory leaks when releasing unique_ptr from C++ to C

Tags: c++, free, unique-ptr, delete-operator

I have a C program that calls a C++ wrapper around a large C++ library. One of the functions of the C++ library is to provide some predictions, and those predictions will be used within C. I'm wondering where I should `free` or `delete` the memory. Here is some example code.

`cpp_wrapper.cpp`

```cpp
#include "cpp_wrapper.h"


uint8_t * run_model(struct_with_model model_struct, const double * input_data) {
  // the model_struct is new'd in C++ in an earlier method

  // I have a method to convert the input data to std::vector for use in C++ code
  std::vector<double> data = get_data(input_data); 

  model_struct->model->LoadData(data);

  model_struct->model->run();

  std::vector<uint8_t> predictions = model_struct->model->GetPredictions();

  std::unique_ptr<uint8_t[]> classValues (new uint8_t[predictions.size()]);

  memcpy(classValues.get(), predictions.data(), sizeof(uint8_t) * predictions.size());

  model_struct->model->ClearData(); //clears data from model for future runs, if necessary

  return classValues.release()
}

void model_delete(model_struct) {
  // method to delete the model_struct when necessary
  delete model_struct;
}
```

I have a `cpp_wrapper.h` header file that declares these functions and calls `extern C` as necessary. On the C side, `c_code.c`:

```c
#include "cpp_wrapper.h"


/*
   There's a bunch of code here for ingesting data, initializing the model_struct, etc
*/

uint8_t * predictions = run_model(model_struct, input_data);

// Do stuff with predictions, as necessary

model_delete(model_struct);

free(predictions); // HERE is the question
```

I `new` the initial variable `classValues` in the C++ code, however I `release` the `std::unique_ptr` as the return of the C++ `run_model` function. My understanding was that when I `release` the memory to C, that the C code was responsible for `free`ing the memory. Is this the case? Should I have a C++ method to delete the `predictions` variable (from C), much like I have a C++ method to delete the `model_struct` variable? I'm confused about how to best manage the memory here. I was advised to not use `malloc` (or `calloc`) in C++, but since I'm passing the values back to C, maybe this is a better option...? I'm not sure.

Comment: Is there any way to avoid C having to take ownership of the allocation?

Comment: You can’t safely `free` something that was `new`d if that contributes anything. All memory that you trust C code to handle ownership of must have been `malloc`d (or any C equivalent).

Comment: If your C code is going to be responsible for cleaning up the allocated memory, then you need to allocate the memory in your C++ code in a way that the C code can deal with.

Comment: The rule is simple: `new` --> `delete`, `new[]` --> `delete[]`, `malloc()` --> `free()`. Why it often causes difficulties for newbies?

Comment: My preference is the direction you head in with `model_delete`. It's generally best if the client has no clue where the memory came from or where it goes. This allows you to change-up the library in the future without invalidating the client code. You might even be able to get away with leaving the data in the `vector` and handing the client a pointer to the `vector`'s internal buffer with `std::vector::data`.

Comment: @273K for me this is a challenge because of the `release` part.

Comment: Seems like the suggestion is that regardless of the `release` command, the memory should be `delete`d in C++. Or otherwise, to preallocate memory in C, and have the function in C++ simply fill in the values to that preallocated vector.

Comment: @user4581301 you suggest to have a C++ method that `delete`s the vector `prediction`. Something like `void delete_predictions(uint8_t * predictions) {delete[] predictions;}`. Is this right?

Comment: Yes. But I'd much prefer not having to do it at all if the library can maintain ownership of the array and dispose of it automatically. The stupider the client can be the happier everyone will be.

Comment: Side note: `std::unique_ptr<uint8_t[]> classValues (new uint8_t[predictions.size()]);` is not 100% rock solid. [`std::make_unique`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique) can fill in those small holes.

Comment: @user4581301 yeah, but unfortunately we're on C++11. I had `make_unique` initially and it wouldn't build.

Comment: everything else aside, might as well drop `unique_ptr` here and just use a raw pointer for `classValues`,, `unique_ptr` isn't doing anything for you.

Comment: So you copy predictions 2 times? Are they so small? Another thing - can you make smart pointer to predictions part of `model_struct`? Then destructor of `model_struct` will clean that memory

Comment: @Slava I think I'm only copying once; in C++, `predictions` gets copied to `classValues`, and then the pointer to `classValues` gets `release`d to C. I suppose my challenge boils down to how to best get the predicted outputs from my model in C++ to C.

Comment: "I think I'm only copying once; in C++, predictions gets copied to classValues" - and `predictions` not copied from `model_struct->model->GetPredictions()`?

Comment: @Slava that's a good point; I think you are probably right. The original library that I'm using stores predictions as `std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<double>>>`, which I know isn't best practice. The `GetPredictions()` method turns that 3D array into a 1D array of `uint8_t`. It would be good to produce a single `uint8_t * predictions` that I could pass to C in one shot.

Comment: Small nitpick: you should change `memcpy(classValues.get(), predictions.data(), sizeof(uint8_t) * predictions.size());` to either `std::copy(predictions.begin(), predictions.end(), classValues.get());` or `std::copy_n(predictions.begin(), predictions.size(), classValues.get());`

Comment: "It would be good to produce a single uint8_t * predictions that I could pass to C in one shot." you can pass data from that vector to C in one shot using `data()` method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest solution is to divide the C++ call into two calls. The first one determines how big the needed buffer is. Then the memory can be allocated in the C part. In the second call the data is copied into this buffer. This way the memory management remains completely in the C part.

Alternatively, the C++ interface must provide a function to clear the memory. The C code calls this when the memory is to be released. The usual rule applies:

- `malloc` -> `free`
- `new` -> `delete`
- `new[]` -> `delete[]`

If I see this correctly, you are implementing the second approach at the moment, but are incorrectly using `new[]` -> `delete`!

Comment: Yeah, I was actually doing a mix. I `new[]`d an array in C++, `release`d that array to C, then used C to `free` the array. I think I'll probably use the second alternative with a C++ method like `void delete_predictions(uint8_t * predictions) {delete[] predictions;}`.

Comment: Whoever that creates sth, is responsible for destroying it too. If the memory was allocated in C++ part, then  C++ part must provide a `dispose` method to the C part. If the memory allocation takes place on C side, then C side must deallocate it.

Comment: PS: I like the approach of implementing in C++, and providing a C API. If mainstream had moved in this direction, codebases would've been lots more maitainable by now. ++OP

Comment: `void init_A(A*); void finish_A(A*)` for automatic objects, and `D* create_D(); void dispose_D(D*);` for dynamically allocated objects.